# Mysql one to one join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I need to perform mysql one to one join for the following condition

table1

```
A    B    CallTime
123  789  5:05
123  789  6:17
123  789  7:45
```

table2

```
A    B    CallTime
789  123  5:20
789  123  6:30
789  123  7:15
789  123  8:20
```

Required result by joining the table is

```
A    B   CallTime
789  123 5:05
789  123 6:17
789  123 7:45
```

How to do this please help

Comment: So what's the criteria?

Comment: In your example, you are merely transposing data from columns A and B in table1.  What exactly are you joining to table2 for in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join

```
select t1.a, t1.b , t1.callTime 
from table1 as t1 
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.a, t2.b , t1.callTime 
from table1 as t1 
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T2.A,
    T2.B,
    T1.CallTime
FROM table1 T1
JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```